# BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml') outputs UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe9'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Wanted to write a script that fills out the tarrifs form (water, heat, electricity) on Python.
But before I wanted to web-scrape the [page](https://domm132.wixsite.com/tsnmichurina/forma-sdachi-pokazanij) (looks super agly, just don't mind). I did:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


req = requests.get(
    'https://domm132.wixsite.com/tsnmichurina/forma-sdachi-pokazanij')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ska19\sublime_projects\script.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(soup)
  File "C:\Users\ska19\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 12506: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 2.8s]
```

I have tried to specify the encoding and ignore errors:

```
req = requests.get(
    'https://domm132.wixsite.com/tsnmichurina/forma-sdachi-pokazanij')
text = req.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Again the error appears:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 12504: character maps to <undefined>
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how either to decode the character correctly, or how to skip it.
Could anyone tell me how to fix this? Sorry for a simple question.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Your code works fine in python3 :)

Comment: Hm, you made this question and I've run a script through my anaconda prompt. Everything worked. Before I used Anaconda user build system. The problem is withing sublime-build. Okay, thanks for your question. I got the problem!

Comment: Thank you guys, something is wrong within my sublime-build system